# Change height with Cubic and duration

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I want to animate the `expandedHeight` of my `SliverAppBar`. I can't use `AnimatedContainer` for that, so I thought that I might be able to write this function on my own.

I got a [cubic](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Cubic-class.html) and a [duration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration-class.html). Now I think I just need an async method changing the `expandedHeight` of my SliverAppBar according to a calculated Bézier curve.

```
animateExpandedHeight(int height) async {
    Cubic c = Curves.fastOutSlowIn;
    Duration d = Duration(milliseconds:800);
    
    while ()
    setState(() {
      eHeight += x;
    });
  }
```

when I change `eHeight` my flexibleSpace of my SliverAppBar will extend to that height.

Does anyone know how to calculate the value for my height in a loop with cubic and duration given?

Thanks a lot!